# MinGW library converted to Windows library gives odd link in VC++6

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mingw, gmp

I used the MinGW `.a` to Windows `.lib` transformation process as detailed in a
thread on the gmp-discuss list, as below (acting against a library created with --disable-shared --enable-static.)

```
cp libgmp.a gmp.a
ranlib gmp.a
mv gmp.a gmp.lib
```

I now have a `.lib` file against which VC++6 seems to have no difficulty linking. What concerns me now is warning messages I'm getting from the link phase:

```
LINK : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol "___mb_cur_max" imported
LINK : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol "__pctype" imported
LINK : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol "__iob" imported
```

At this point in the proceedings these make no difference to the running of
my DLL (which wraps certain GMP functionality). But is that good enough?
Will having these three symbols from `libgmp.a` linked in to my Windows DLL
end up biting me later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else had a similar problem and [the fix](http://opensees.berkeley.edu/community/viewtopic.php?t=2267) was relatively simple.